How to get rid of critical vulnerabilities of jetty-websocket ? (CVE-2017-7657 CVE-2017-7658)
I am working on the fork of guacamole-client
I(and also original project) has depedency:
   <!-- Jetty 8 servlet API (websocket)  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.1.v20120215</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

Based on result of security analyzer this dependency has 2 critical vulnurabilities:

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-7657
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-7658

Based on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/8.1.1.v20120215

This vulnerabilities come from its dependencies:
Looks like those vulnerabilities are taken from:
org.eclipse.jetty » jetty-server » 8.1.1.v20120215


I see that the latest version of  jetty-websocket is 8.2.0.v20160908 but it was released in 2016 and it still contains this issue because it references jetty-server 8.2.0.v20160908
Those vulnerabilities are fixed in jetty-server » 9.3.24.v20180605
but there are no correspondng version of jetty-websocket so I have no idea how can I fix this issue.
Is there way to get rid of those vunerabilities ?
P.S.
I have imports:
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket.Connection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketServlet;

What do I have to replace them with ?

Jetty 8 was EOL back in 2014. Jetty 9 went EOL in 2022. Jetty 10 and Jetty 11 went EOL  in 2024.  The only version supported right now is Jetty 12. - https://jetty.org/download.html#what-version-do-i-use

Use a newer version that doesn't contain the vulnerability.

@aled newer version for the same artifact is absent. Based on Joakim answer - I have to use another artifact to replace old one.


Jetty 8 was EOL back in 2014.
Jetty 9 went EOL in 2022.
Jetty 10 and Jetty 11 went EOL in 2024.

The only version supported right now is Jetty 12. - https://jetty.org/download.html#what-version-do-i-use
If you need support for the old javax.servlet namespace, use the ee8 environment in Jetty 12.
Note that WebSocket has undergone large changes since Jetty 8.

The Jetty 8 implementation of WebSocket was back when WebSocket was still a draft spec.
Jetty 9 made changes to support the released WebSocket spec. (and the original jetty-websocket artifact was split up)
Jetty 10 made changes to support WebSocket on HTTP/2 (and more splits in the websocket artifacts were made)
Jetty 12 made changes to support WebSocket on any protocol (even oddball ones like UnixSocket) (and even more websocket artifacts were made)

These changes also changed the maven coordinates.
See the migration guides for coordinate changes.

Migration Guide 9.4 to 10/11 : https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/programming-guide/migration/94-to-10.html
Migration Guide 10/11 to 12 : https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/programming-guide/migration/11-to-12.html


Looks like I need megration guide from 8 to 12

@gstackoverflow maybe from 8 to 9, 9 to 10, etc.

The migration guide from Jetty 8 to Jetty 9 existed about 8 years ago.  It was on wiki.eclipse.org, but that service has been deprecated, scheduled for shutdown, and the content removed about 5 years ago.

It is sad that it doesn't exist anymore

@Joakim Erdfelt
Could you give me an advise what do I have to replace with for         <dependency>             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>             <artifactId>jetty-websocket</artifactId>             <version>8.1.1.v20120215</version>             <scope>provided</scope>         </dependency>

Jetty 9 made changes to support the released WebSocket spec. (and the original jetty-websocket artifact was split up)

what do I have to use instead ?

I cannot answer that, as it's too long ago. (honestly, we are working on Jetty 12.1 right now, and you are asking about something that was 8 major versions ago. yes 8, versioning in Jetty is not semver)  I vaguely remember that it depends on what technologies you are using - https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-websocket
